# Adding multiple conditions in regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, sap-successfactors

I am a beginner in using regex. I was trying to build a validation in SuccessFactors Onboarding 1.0. for a cell phone number field. People should be able to add up to 15 digits and the following characters: + ( ) and spaces. I want to disable people from entering letters (i.e. ext). If the format doesn't match, the system should throw an error. The error is configured within the page settings, and the regex is a condition, which when not matched causes the error popping up on the screen, hence the error message doesn't need to be a part of the expression.

I figured out the following code: `^[\d]{1,15}$|\|/[^a-z]+x/$`, but that code only enables the validation of number of characters plus disables adding letters (when testing it seems to disable both, upper and lower cases). I don't know how to add a third condition which would allow adding the characters mentioned above. I tried with this code: `[\d]{1,15}$|\[^a-z]+x\|\(?:+()\$`, but this code doesn't allow for adding the additional characters plus disables the error message, user cannot continue processing to next page, but the error doesn't occurs on the screen, only the red asterisk next to the field.

Can I ask anyone to help me figuring out how to add the last piece of validation correctly, so that characters such as + () and up 15 digits are allowed, but everything else would pop up an error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code sort of

```
if (string.contains(Regex("[^\d\+\(\) ]")) throw Exception() else accept
if (string.length > 15 || string.isEmpty()) throw Exception() else accept
```

if you need more strict condition, make an exempla what is correct input, and what isn't correct

Answer (score 1):

No worries, with the exception of a selected few, we're all beginners in using RegEx!

On a general note, restricting what is considered to be a valid or invalid notation of a phone number might not be a good idea at all. Sometimes you'll see the extension number at the end being visually separated by a minus sign (as in "0123 45 678 - 9"). Some people might add the country code or dialling code in paranthesis, others won't.

Also consider numbers entered (or pasted from a source) with non-Western characters, as the chinese parenthesis `（ ）` (they look similar, but are actually characters of their own with more whitespace around them!) - shouldn't those be considered valid as well?

If someone wants to enter an invalid number, they will anyway ("555-00000000" ...)!

But if you really want to restrict the string entered to numbers and the characters `()+-` , this is the regular expression you'd need:

```js
const rx = /^[0-9()+\- ]+$/;

// should be false:
console.log(rx.test("abc 123"));

// should be true:
console.log(rx.test("+49 123 456 789 - 0"));
console.log(rx.test("+49 (0) 123 456 789 - 0"));
console.log(rx.test("555-000 0000"));

// this will fail, because of the use of Chinese parenthesis,
// which is the only difference to the second number in the  previous block
console.log(rx.test("+49 （0）123 456 789 - 0"));

// of course, these would also be considered valid,
// unless you'd implement some more sophisticated checks
// - but is it really worth the trouble?
console.log(rx.test("((( 12345"));
console.log(rx.test("++++"));
```

Let me break the expression down for you:

```
/^[0-9()+\- ]+$/
 ^- beginning of the string
  ^- start of the character group
   ^- all the characters we want to allow
      (we have to escape the -, because otherwise
      it would denote an invalid character range)
            ^- end of the character group
             ^- + means: at least one, or more of those characters
              ^- end of the tring
```

A good place to build, check and verify your regular expressions, especially in the beginning, are regex testing tools like (in no specific order): [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/), or [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Adding to the in-code comment `but is it really worth the trouble?`: it most likely is not. Therefore you could think of other ways to validate the phone numbers, such as: sending a validation code to the phone number that has been entered, and only considering it valid when the they validate that code

Comment: Hello. Well, the answer to the question if it is worth is simply I got the requirement to find a solution, the client is quite strict in terms of what can be entered because wants to store "clean data". For me this is more of a Shakespeare's question "to be or not to be" - I don't really care :) The code which @Constantin Groß suggested is a good solution - thanks a lot! But one thing is missing. The number of digits should be between 1 and 15, the suggested regex doesn't do that. I am not sure how to "plug in" this limit into the code. How can this be achieved?

Comment: One more thing. I learned from the resources suggested by Constantin that | stands for "or", which is why I think my initial try failed, there were three or conditions. Anyone know what will mean "and" in regex? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: So basically, your client wants "clean data" no matter the user experience. Maybe they aren't even aware of the fact that it may deter users, so this is definitely worth talking about to them.

Comment: There's no special character needed for the "and" relationship. Just put the two strings or character classes you want to join one after another